# problems with curl_exec($ch)

Tags: xml, curl

Why it always returns true?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string),'SOAPAction:urn:RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint','Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' )); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data===true){
        echo"<script>location.assign('utente.php')</script>";
      }else{
        echo"<script>location.assign('index.php?a=0')</script>";
        }
```

I tried many solutions but none have been successful

Comment: you check if it returns `===true`, but you also set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, so it should NEVER return bool(true) , it will either return a string, OR return bool(false) . but with CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , it should NEVER return bool(true).

Comment: how do I resolve? because I did not understand

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why this will help.